# Delete user account after checkout completion

Tags: rules, ubercart

Im trying to create a rule that deletes an user account after checkout completion for New users, but it is not working. Can anyone please help me to figure out what is wrong? after checkout completion, check if user is not admin or any other role, then delete the account. After anonymous checkout, an user account is created (blocked, registered).

```
{ "rules_delete_user_account_after_checkout" : {
  "LABEL" : "Delete User Account after Checkout",
  "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
  "WEIGHT" : "3",
  "OWNER" : "rules",
  "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "php", "uc_cart" ],
  "ON" : { "uc_checkout_complete" : [] },
  "IF" : [
    {
      "NOT data_is" : {
        "data" : [ "order:customer:roles" ],
        "value" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
      }
    }
  ],
  "DO" : [
    { "php_eval" : { "code" : "\/\/ Delete the user.\r\nuser_delete(NULL, [order-uid]);" } }
  ]
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a user after checkout is a bad idea. I assume you know this, but the client is asking/forcing you to do this.

check this [link - automatically delete all Ubercart-created users](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/15389/cron_automatically_delete_all_users_automaticallycreated_ubercart),  this has a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Link-only answers are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange. May you edit your answer to make it independent from the external site?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the link. I did followed the recommendation from the post.

1. After saving a new user account, Customer completes checkout: assign
   new user an "ubercart" role.
2. Customer completes checkout, User has the ubercart role and user is not admin or any of the other roles, execute php code:
   // Delete the user.
   user_delete($order->uid);